# How to guard a route after redirecting from server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

First things firsts, I have my REST API "built with Express js" running on `localhost:4000`, and my react app running on `localhost:3000`.

So, when a user registers for a new account from the sign-up form in the react app, I send a POST request to the backend which generates an encrypted token and sends an email to the user containing a link with this format: `http://localhost:4000/verify?id=<encrypted_key>`.

The user clicks the link in his email which hits the `/verify` endpoint. Inside the verify API I decrypt the key and verify the user's email in the database -*I'm using MongoDB*- and then redirect the user to the react app to this route: `http://localhost:3000/verified`.

Everything works fine except when I visit `http://localhost:3000/verified` without being redirected to it like the case I said above.

**Therefore, what I want is to guard this route so that I can view it only if I was redirected from the backend's API.**

Comment: A typical way is that once you verify the user, you drop a secure cookie that is specific to that user and the subsequent routes require a valid secure cookie.

Comment: Can I do that with res.cookie(...)? @jfriend00

Comment: You can set the cookie with `res.cookie()`, but you will also then have to verify it (probably with middleware) for every route that should be protected.  And the cookie needs to be not easy for someone to make their own (usually something encrypted that is unique to that user)